How to add custom type conversion for configuration
I have a toml file for configuration where a few sections contain Crontab expressions that I want to be automatically parsed instead of capturing it as a string then parsing it.
public record TestConfig(NCrontab.CrontabSchedule Schedule);

_builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.AddTomlFile("Config.toml");
    options.AddTomlFile("Config.Develop.toml");
});

_builder.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
{
    var test = ctx.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TestConfig)).Get<TestConfig>() ?? throw new Exception();
}

I've tried using a custom TypeConverter but it doesn't seem to be selective of the expected type so all string values go through this converter, so the values that aren't crontab just get converted to null
public class CronTabConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object? ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo? culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value is string strValue)
        {
            return CrontabSchedule.TryParse(strValue);
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public static void RegisterTypeConverter()
    {
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(string), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(CronTabConverter)));
    }
}

I can see that this might be possible with JsonConverters but I don't know how to register the custom converter for AddJsonFile.
I am not opposed to switching the config file to Json if it can be done that way.

Your problem is not related to cron, so there is no point involving this in question. Same story with configuration. Your problem is customizing serialization of JSON, and what is important here is to mention which one do you use.
This is my factory for serializer for Text.Json:
public static class TextOptionsFactory
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0
    public static void CustomizeJsonOptions(JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70352
        options.IncludeFields = true;
        options.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
        options.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All);
        options.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; //JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

        options.Converters.Add(new OptionConverterFactory());
        options.Converters.Add(new ResultConverterFactory());
        options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        options.Converters.Add(new LanguageIdentifierConverter());
        options.Converters.Add(new WordIdentifierConverter());
        options.Converters.Add(new TranslationIdentifierConverter());
        options.Converters.Add(new CodeConverter());
        options.Converters.Add(new LocalIdConverter());
    }

    public static JsonSerializerOptions DisableRequiredConstraint(this JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties
        options.TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
        {
            Modifiers =
            {
                static typeInfo =>
                {
                    if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                        return;

                    foreach (JsonPropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeInfo.Properties)
                    {
                        // Strip IsRequired constraint from every property.
                        propertyInfo.IsRequired = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return options;
    }

    public static JsonSerializerOptions BuildJsonOptions(bool compact)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = !compact,
        };

        CustomizeJsonOptions(options);

        return options;
    }
}

One of the converters:
public sealed class WordIdentifierConverter : JsonConverter<WordId>
{
    public override WordId Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        new WordId(reader.GetInt32());

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        WordId wordId,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteNumberValue(wordId.Id);

    public override void WriteAsPropertyName(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        WordId wordId,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WritePropertyName(wordId.Id.ToString());

    public override WordId ReadAsPropertyName(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        new WordId(reader.GetInt32());
}

And settings things up, depending when you need this -- I see you need this for reading a file, I don't have ready to use example for this, but you should find something similar as here:
var mvc_builder = builder.Services.AddControllers();
mvc_builder.AddJsonOptions(json =>   TextOptionsFactory.CustomizeJsonOptions(json.JsonSerializerOptions));

